# mac terminal login costs too much time

Tags: macos, terminal

Every time I open a new terminal it costs about 3-5 seconds to login , plz see the screenshot.[image]

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I'm guessing you added something to your login profile...

Comment: @SteffX question is why login cost so much time ? It's never been like this until I install oh-my-zsh , but uninstall oh-my-zsh doesn't make any senses. and  how can I reduce time it costs.

Comment: @MarkSetchell where is my login profile , plz tell me and I'll check that.

Comment: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_3.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminal seems to save every command to ASL (Apple System Log) log files and it can become cumbersome. Many reports that deleting ASL log files speed up the Terminal. Try:

```
sudo rm /private/var/log/asl/*.asl
```

and relaunch Terminal.